# Bitlocker recovery will not work on swapped hard drive

Tags: encryption

I had a laptop die (no power) so I swapped the HD into a new machine but cannot complete the Bitlocker recovery, says invalid key. I have no way of accessing the HD on the old laptop since it's "dead".

Any help would be great.